# Automating AD using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I tried to automate AD by following this link :

```
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrenoden/2016/07/26/deploying-a-dc-to-azure-iaas-with-arm-and-dsc/
```

I have tried using templates that are available but I have a problem there. There are being deployed successfully, but the roles are not visible. Only **Group Policy Management** is visible, not all. So, I am following this.

This is the error I face:

```
16:17:11 - [ERROR] Get-AzureRmEnvironment : The term 'Get-AzureRmEnvironment' is not recognized 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] correct and try again.
16:17:11 - [ERROR] At line:1 char:171
16:17:11 - [ERROR] + ... re_PS_Data_Collection = 'true' }; if ((Get-AzureRmEnvironment -Name ' ...
16:17:11 - [ERROR] +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmEnvironment:String)  
16:17:11 - [ERROR]    [], CommandNotFoundException
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
16:17:11 - [ERROR]  
16:17:11 - [ERROR] Get-AzureRmEnvironment : The term 'Get-AzureRmEnvironment' is not recognized 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] correct and try again.
16:17:11 - [ERROR] At line:1 char:2323
16:17:11 - [ERROR] + ...  'asrsnraju@hotmail.com' -Environment (Get-AzureRmEnvironment -Name ' ...
16:17:11 - [ERROR] +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmEnvironment:String)  
16:17:11 - [ERROR]    [], CommandNotFoundException
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
16:17:11 - [ERROR]  
16:17:11 - [ERROR] & : The script 'Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1' cannot be run because the 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the 
16:17:11 - [ERROR] script are missing: AzureRM.Resources.
16:17:11 - [ERROR] At line:1 char:2369
16:17:11 - [ERROR] + ... eCloud')));&'C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyD ...
16:17:11 - [ERROR] +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Deploy-AzureResourceGroup. 
16:17:11 - [ERROR]    ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
16:17:11 - [ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresMissingModules
16:17:11 - [ERROR]  
16:17:11 - 
16:17:11 - Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.
```

Then, I have done this to my powershell to try and solve it . But nothing changed :

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -Environment (Get-AzureRmEnvironment -Name AzureUSGovernment)
```

Do I need to add something to my powershell??

Comment: What version of Azure PowerShell are you running?

Comment: PS C:\Users\admin> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion . This the command I used to check the version. It returned Major -- 5 , Minor --- 1 , Build --- 14393, Revision --- 187

Comment: In powershell ISE, I could find Get-AzureRmEnvironment module to the right. So, that means I have that  module. Then, why the error??    In the command above, I gave the name as AzureUSGovernment and I am running my deployment in SouthEast Asia. Can I do that??

Comment: Are you running this from Visual Studio?  If so, can you bring up a PS window in VS (CTRL+SHIFT+\) and run: Get-Module -ListAvailable AzureRM.Resources and see what you get?

Comment: I restarted my laptop. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else coming across this, I hit the same issue trying out an Azure quickstart and it was because I didn't have the Azure PowerShell cmdlets installed. Steps are detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.0.0) and are:

1. Make sure you have PowerShellGet installed, requires Powershell 5.x, if on a lower version you need the [PackageManagement modules](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746217)
2. Install the Azure PowerShell tools (from within an elevated PowerShell window):

   Install-Module AzureRM
3. Make sure to restart Visual Studio, then retry your Azure script